# Why does the index of a `char **` type give the whole string?

Tags: c++11, pointers, char

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char c[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
    char *pc = c;
    char **ppc = &pc;
    cout << ppc[0] << endl;
}
```

This prints `abc` as output. Why does the index of a pointer to pointer to `char` return the whole string? Here, `ppc` only points to another pointer that points to a single `char`. How does it know about the whole string and why would it return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand what `std::cout` is and why it treats a `char*` as a "string".

Lets start:

`std::cout` is an instance of an `std::ostream` and `std::ostream` has a lot of operators. What does it mean?

The implementation of `std::ostream` can, but only as an example here, written like:

```
 class ostream
 {
     // ... a lot more code for constructors and others
     ostream& operator <<( const int );
     ostream& operator <<( const double );
     ostream& operator <<( char* );        <<< this is the implementation you search for!
     // a long list of more special overloads follow
 };
```

And the implementation simply puts out the "string" which the char* points to.

What you see is simply a special overload of the `operator<<` for the `std::ostream` class.

OK, the real implementation uses a non-member overload, but that is not important for understanding how `std::ostream` works in principal.

For more details see: [std::ostream::operator<<()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

> Character and character string arguments (e.g., of type char or const char*) are handled by the non-member overloads of operator<<. Attempting to output a character using the member function call syntax (e.g., std::cout.operator<<('c');) will call one of overloads (2-4) and output the numerical value. Attempting to output a character string using the member function call syntax will call overload (7) and print the pointer value instead.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent:

```
cout << ppc[0] << endl;
cout << *( ppc + 0 ) << endl;
cout << *ppc << endl;
cout << *(&pc) << endl;
cout << pc << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! But this made me realize that the root of my confusion lies in why printing `pc` prints the whole string; is a pointer to `char` somehow treated as a string?

Comment: Yes, because `char*` pointers are frequently used for (NUL-terminated) strings. This comes from C++'s C heritage.